# Panoramic Image manipulation in android environment

Tags: android

I want to create my panorama player for my application, where a user can move the image left-right up-down.

Could someone point a good tutorial/guidelines for this purpose. 
I have seen most of the examples and tutorials, but a bit confused.

Do I have to use `Bitmap`s and `Matrix` for manipulation or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used it, but it looks like [AndoridBigImage](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/AndroidBigImage) might work for you.